# Is it possible to use dynamodb remotely - not local - while testing locally with AWS SAM CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, command-line-interface

In many cases, the question is *how to use aws sam cli with a "local" dynamodb*,

my question is about: how to use dynamodb that is in production, so not local.

my local nodejs script, for instance, looks like this:

```
const doc = require('dynamodb-doc');
const dynamo = new doc.DynamoDB();
dynamo.query(queryParams, function(err, data) {
             if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
             else     console.log('data: '+ data);           // successful response
         });
```

I start my script with `sam local invoke --no-event` - when i query a table, how can i use a specific AWS remote resource?

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to use the specific remote resource when invoking your lambdas, like DynamoDB in your case, you can run your invoke command with the profile desired, ex: production as follow.

```
sam local invoke --no-event --profile production
```

You will need to have the production profile configured in your aws credentials file. if you haven't done that already you can do that as follow:

```
aws configure --profile production
```